# Custom RecyclerView's LayoutManager. Automeasuring after animation finished on item delete

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-recyclerview

I've created a [custom layout manager](https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager) for `RecyclerView`. I've enabled auto-measuring in constructor of my manager via `setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)`

When `RecyclerView`'s `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content` with this property `LayoutManager` is able to measure height of `RecyclerView` according to items inside it. It works perfectly, but when i delete the last item at bottom, the deleting animation is playing at that moment, it causes `RecyclerView` to measure it's height to result height before the animation have finished.

Look at this gif. 
[image]
Where green background is a RecyclerView

As you may guessed this behaviour is correct for adding item, because in that case container should be measured before an animation

How can i handle this situation to make processing `RecyclerView` auto-measure after animation have finished?
I have all child positioning logic in `onLayoutChildren` but i think posting it doesn't required for this question and could be so broad and unclear.

Probably i should handle `onMeasure` interceptor of layoutManager manually (It called 4 times when item have deleted (one time before onItemsRemoved invocation)). So i could set measured height there, based on height, which i receive when deletion have started:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
    requestSimpleAnimationsInNextLayout();
    if (!isAutoMeasureEnabled()) {
        setMeasuredDimension(getWidth(), preHeight);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemsRemoved(RecyclerView recyclerView, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    super.onItemsRemoved(recyclerView, positionStart, itemCount);
    setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);

    new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
            requestSimpleAnimationsInNextLayout();
            requestLayout();
        }
    }, 400);

    preHeight = //calculate height before deletion
}
```

As you can see, i provided a handler with approximately delayed `400ms` value, which execute auto measure after animations finished, so this could lead to needed results, but the duration of animation isn't static and i don't see any possibility to listen animation finished event.

So, desired behaviour:

[image]

By the way auto-measuring of LinearLayoutManager works with same way

If you pointed me to right direction with just text description of algorithm it would be enough.

Comment: I am not able to improve quality of my question, because you've downvoted me without any comment

Comment: The question is perfectly asked & perfectly answered in my opinion...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've at last figured it out.
So, my solution:

Subscribe to dataChanges event in `onAdapterChanged` method and disable automeasuring.

```
 @Override
public void onAdapterChanged(RecyclerView.Adapter oldAdapter,
                             RecyclerView.Adapter newAdapter) {
    newAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            // on api 16 this is invoked before onItemsRemoved
            super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
            /** we detected removing event, so should process measuring manually
             */
            setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);
        }
    });
     //Completely scrap the existing layout
    removeAllViews();
}
```

In `onMeasure` in case auto-measuring disabled measure manually, use current size:

```
 @Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);

    if (!isAutoMeasureEnabled()) {
        // we should perform measuring manually
        // so request animations
        requestSimpleAnimationsInNextLayout();
        //keep size until remove animation will be completed
        setMeasuredDimension(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Perform auto-measuring after animation finished:

```
 @Override
public void onItemsRemoved(final RecyclerView recyclerView, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    super.onItemsRemoved(recyclerView, positionStart, itemCount);
    //subscribe to next animations tick
    postOnAnimation(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //listen removing animation
            recyclerView.getItemAnimator().isRunning(new RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationsFinished() {
                    //when removing animation finished return auto-measuring back
                    setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
                    // and process onMeasure again
                    requestLayout();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This callbacks chain is safe, because `postOnAnimation` runnable won't be executed in case layout manager is detached from `RecyclerView`

Comment: Please add that also method `isAutoMeasureEnabled()` should be overridden as in LinearLayoutManager it always returns true (yes, it's hardcoded there) so your code will not work without this.

Comment: `onItemRangeRemoved` is called each time the adapter notifies that an item or a range of items were removed but there are cases when the count of the items removed = 0 (e.g. an expandable recycler view - when the group is collapsed and it contains no items). So in order to cover this case as well you have to add a check inside `onItemRangeRemoved` and call `setAutoMeasureEnabled(false)` only if `itemCount > 0`.

Answer (score 3):

@Beloo's answer was not working for me, I suspect because `setAutoMeasureEnabled` has been deprecated. I was able to get it working by only overriding `onItemsRemoved`, `onMeasure` and also `isAutoMeasureEnabled`.

First create a variable that will keep track of the `isAutoMeasureEnabled` property:

`private boolean autoMeasureEnabled = true;`

Then override `isAutoMeasureEnabled` to use the variable:

```
@Override
public boolean isAutoMeasureEnabled (){
    return autoMeasureEnabled;
}
```

Now you can set the variable `autoMeasureEnabled` at will. Override `onItemsRemoved`:

```
@Override
public void onItemsRemoved(@NonNull final RecyclerView recyclerView, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    super.onItemsRemoved(recyclerView, positionStart, itemCount);
    autoMeasureEnabled = false;
    postOnAnimation(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.getItemAnimator().isRunning(new RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationsFinished() {
                    autoMeasureEnabled = true;
                    requestLayout();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Also override `onMeasure` just like in @Beloo's answer:

```
    @Override
public void onMeasure(@NotNull RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, @NotNull RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);

    if (!isAutoMeasureEnabled()) {
        // we should perform measuring manually
        // so request animations
        requestSimpleAnimationsInNextLayout();
        //keep size until remove animation will be completed
        setMeasuredDimension(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

This seems to work. The animation is fast, but timed correctly.

Comment: This works for me, however I did need to override the function `onAdapterChanged` like @Beloo did.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use transitions on RecyclerView itself so that it animates its own bound changes too.

From: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

> Note that although RecyclerView animates its children, it does not animate its own bounds changes. If you would like to animate the RecyclerView bounds as they change, you can use the Transition APIs.

So as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions?utm_campaign=android_launch_supportlibrary23.2_022216&utm_medium=blog&utm_source=anddev#NoScenes) `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView)` should work fine.